# Is there any way to remove that square tile from discord mobile version?

Tags: discord

With recent update came that floating square tile, any way to completly remove it from iphone app or hide it in some way?

Search through does not gave any good what to turn off to hide that tile from layout,
discovered that came to concerete account, mine another account does not have that new feature

[image]